# Remove Html tag from selected text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags

I am new at **`JavaScript`** and I tried to add a new tag to the selected word.
I did it like this:

```
function addBoldTag() {
                 var highlight = window.getSelection();
               if(highlight.toString().length>=1){
               var range = highlight.getRangeAt(0); 
                var selectionContents = range.extractContents(); 
                 var boldtag = document.createElement("b"); 
                 boldtag.style.cssText = " color :blue; ";
                 boldtag.appendChild(selectionContents); 
                 range.insertNode(boldtag); 
                 highlight.removeAllRanges(); 
                 }
}
```

I have a new issue now, I'd like to unwrap or remove selected word's tag, the way`HTMLeditors` does it, but I can't find a way to do it. I've found **`Jquery`**, but I have to do with **`pure javascript`**.

Comment: You seem to be going about this a strange way. If you where wanting to do this for a website, you could use css. If you want to do it for a text editor, then a regular expression would be better

Comment: Where are the texts? Are those texts on your web page? In a textbox?

Comment: @atmd I want to use for modify epub files, in javaFX ,I tried to use regular expression but I have got a lot of problem for xml standarts, and also I don't believe regelar expression is ideal way for this

Comment: I'd recommend you update your question, there is no mention in it of the things in your comment

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look below:

```js
const selectedRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
const element = document.createElement('strong');
selectedRange.surroundContents(element);
```

I hope it would help you out